# Восстановление репозитория GitHub

Tags: git, github, репозиторий, восстановление

Можно ли восстановить репозитория на гитхабе, который я сам и удалил, имея его копию на локальном компьютере?
Интересует восстановление со всеми комитами.
Т.е. вернуться к тому состоянию которое было до этого.

Comment: Если он у вас есть локально со всеми коммитами, то просто залейте его назад. GitHub этож просто удаленка

Comment: Т.е. push и моя проблема решена? Мне нужно,что бы были видны изменения в коммитах.

Comment: Локальная копия хранит всю копию репозиторию на гитхабе, поэтому кодовую базу можно восстановить до последнего git pull. Issue вы так не восстановите, а код - пожалуйста.

Comment: Дома проверю, отпишусь.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Создаете новый репозиторий на Github (название ваше). На экране вы увидите инструкцию, как соединить наш локальный репозиторий со вновь созданным.

Добавляем удаленный репозиторий (по протоколу SSH) под именем origin (вместо origin можно использовать любое другое имя).

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:myuser/project.git
```

Можем просмотреть результат добавления с помощью команды:

```
git remote -v
```

Если все было правильно сделано, то увидим:

```
origin git@github.com:myuser/project.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:myuser/project.git (push)
```

Для того, чтобы отменить регистрацию удаленного репозитария введите:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Это может понадобиться, если вы захотите поменять SSH доступ на HTTPS. После этого можно добавить его опять, например под именем github и протоколом HTTPS.

```
git remote add github https://github.com/myuser/project.git
```

Следующей командой вы занесете все изменения, которые были сделаны в локальном репозитории на Github.

```
git push -u github master
```

Ключ `-u` используется для того, чтобы установить связь между удаленным репозиторием github и вашей веткой `master`. Все дальнейшие изменения вы можете переносить на удаленный репозиторий упрощенной командой.

```
git push
```

Comment: Если бы  я мог, я бы вас обнял . вот на сколько я доволен, спасибо.

Comment: @L.F.C. наверное приятно читать такие комментарии к ответу, как выше (+) Что-то в последнее время не отвечали совсем. На работе весь?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT если честно да, учёба плюс работа, пропадаю бывают заскочу на SO на пару минут и то сил нет уже и желания о чем то думать